# Classe não Reconhecida C# WINDOWS FORMS

Tags: c#

Estou com um novo problema no mesmo método, no lugar em negrito e itálico acusa um problema de classe não reconhecida, alguma dica de como resolver?
Código a seguir:

```
public static void CompactarMdb(string caminhoaccdb){
        JRO.JetEngine jetEngine = (JRO.JetEngine)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("JRO.JetEngine"));
        var arquivoTemporario = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        arquivoTemporario = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(arquivoTemporario, "accdb");
        string templateConnectionString = "Data Source={0}; Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;";
        string connectionStringFonte = string.Format(templateConnectionString, caminhoaccdb);
        string connectionStringTemp = string.Format(templateConnectionString, arquivoTemporario);
        ***jetEngine.CompactDatabase(connectionStringFonte, connectionStringTemp);***
        System.IO.File.Copy(arquivoTemporario, caminhoaccdb, true);
        System.IO.File.Delete(arquivoTemporario);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar a referência ao arquivo

> msjro.dll

Localize ele no seu PC, no meu caso estava no:

> C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-m..replication-objects_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.16299.15_none_ad8010ef4b16f751

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/230501/how-to-compact-microsoft-access-database-through-ado

**Update**

Após discussão no chat funcionou com o seguinte código:

Necessário adicionar referência ao

> Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library

```
string sourceDbSpec = @"C:\temp\testdb.accdb"; 
string destinationDbSpec = @"C:\temp\compactado.accdb"; 

// Required COM reference for project: 
// Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library 
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine(); 
try 
{ 
    dbe.CompactDatabase(sourceDbSpec, destinationDbSpec); 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message); 
}
```

Comment: Fiz a referencia, porém o erro persiste, não descarto ter feito errado, alguma dica de referenciar ?

Comment: No Solution Explorer clique com o botão direito sobre References e Add Reference. Abrirá uma janela, clique em Browser e localize a DLL, após isso pode dar OK. Observe depois que essa nova referencia ficará dentro da aba referencias lá. Aqui eu fiz o mesmo o código compilou normalmente.

Comment: Fiz, mas o problema persiste, infelizmente

Comment: Mas chega a compilar (build) ou nem isso? ou dá erro quando vai executar?

Comment: Compilou e rodou, mas quando executo o código que postei aqui, o erro da classe não reconhecida persiste

Comment: Vou testar aqui, vou caçar um mdb pra fazer.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69373/discussion-between-thiago-loureiro-and-and).

Comment: Resolveu o problema, muito obrigado pela ajuda no chat. Abraço!